# Como usar palavras reservadas no SQL

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Preciso inserir um valor na tabela, mas existe um campo com o nome 'Status', que é uma palavra reservada do SQL. Como faço para usar esse campo no INSERT?

```
insert into <<tabela>> (status) values ('A')
```

O erro retornado é:

> ```
> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
> ```

Comment: qual o `SGBD` que você está usando? E o que me parece mais errado é usar `<>` como nome de tabela.

Comment: Não estou usando <> como nome de tabela, na verdade eu coloquei <<nome_da_tabela>>, mas o stackoverflow sobrescreveu. Estou usando o SQL Server 2016

Comment: Qual o erro que você está tendo? O `SQL Server` permite essa coluna normalmente.

Comment: Eu preciso inserir uma quantidade grande de valores em uma tabela, mas estou recebendo o erro de quantidade de colunas na tabela.                                 
 There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.                                     Só que estou procurando qual é o campo que eu coloquei a mais e preciso saber se é o campo Status, porque ele fica azul como palavra reservada.

Comment: Seu erro não é esse então. A tradução do seu erro é "
Existem mais colunas na instrução INSERT do que os valores especificados na cláusula VALUES. O número de valores na cláusula VALUES deve corresponder ao número de colunas especificadas na instrução INSERT.". Provavelmente seu `INSERT` não é esse que você informou na pergunta.

Comment: No PostgreSQL você deve utilizar aspas duplas (delimited identifier ou quoted identifier): "status".

Comment: Eu preciso saber se tenho que usar algo como aspas duplas no SQL Server em palavras reservadas quando coloco como nome de campo.

Comment: Leia o meu comentário. Seu erro não tem a ver com a coluna `status`.

Comment: Eu sei que o problema é a quantidade de valores, mas a palavra status no banco está como reservada, não deve ser do padrão ANSI. Eu quero saber se tem algo como aspas pra usar em palavras reservadas no caso de colocar como nome de campos, pra ver se esse pode ser o problema (não identificar a palavra status como campo, logo não identificar o valor que estou inserindo nesse campo).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No SQLServer, quando uso palavras reservadas como nome de campo na tabela, preciso colocar aspas pro SQL reconhecer como campo.
No caso, a palavra reservada que eu estava usando era Status (o sql estava reconhecendo como palavra reservada), mas essa palavra não faz parte do padrão ANSI.

Comment: Sua resposta está incorreta. Como eu mostrei abaixo é possível sim usar a palavra `status`

Answer (score 0):

A princípio a palavra `STATUS` não é uma palavra reservada do `SQL Server` como você pode ver na [lista de palavras chaves reservadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Testei no [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2348dcb53087f581a8b189a70641262) e seu exemplo (sem <<>>) funciona normalmente.

Pelo seu erro o problema não é com a coluna `STATUS` e sim com o fato de você ter colocado mais colunas no `INSERT` do que na cláusula `VALUES`. O seu erro, em tradução livre, é o seguinte:

> ```
> Existem mais colunas na instrução INSERT do que os valores especificados na cláusula VALUES. O número de valores na cláusula VALUES deve corresponder ao número de colunas especificadas na instrução INSERT.
> ```